# for vs. if loop *incorrect selection*

Tags: python, python-2.7

Trying to create a fill in the blanks quiz.

If I use a for loop when the answer is incorrect will always return to FIRST element on the list, is there any way to bypass this? or use a different loop?

See my full code below.
IT IS NOT FINAL
Will only work on EASY answer selection.
The issue will appear when answering correctly FIRST blank(Imagine) and failing on the second one.

Any help will be highly apreciatted.

```
imag = '***1*** there is no heaven, It is ***2*** if you try, No hell below us, Above us only sky, ***1*** all the people living for today, ***1*** there is no ***3***, It is not hard to do, Nothing to kill or die for, And no religion too, ***1*** all the people living life in ***4***.'
imag_ans = ['Imagine', 'easy', 'heaven', 'peace']
blanks = ['***1***', '***2***', '***3***', '***4**']    

def level():
    print 'Please select Level? (Easy / Medium / Hard)'
    global a
    a = raw_input()
    if a == 'Easy':
        return attempts()
    if a == 'Medium':
        return 'Med'
    if a == 'Hard':
        return 'Hard'
    else :
        print 'Invalid option'
        print '\n'
        return level()

def attempts():
    print 'How many attempts will you need?'
    global numberofatt
    numberofatt = raw_input()
    try:
        float(numberofatt)
    except ValueError:
        print "Please enter a number for attempts"
        return attempts()
    numberofatt = int(numberofatt)
    if numberofatt <= 0 :
        print 'Please enter a positive number'
        return attempts()
    else :
        return quiz(a)

def quiz(level):
    i = 0
    global user_ans
    global i
    print 'Please fill in the blanks, you have ' + str(numberofatt) + ' attempts'
    for blank in blanks:
        print 'Fill in blank' + blank 
        user_ans = raw_input()
        if user_ans == imag_ans[i]:
            i = i + 1
            global imag
            imag = imag.replace(blank, user_ans)
            print "Correct!"
            print imag  
        else :
            return att()

n = 1
def att():
    if n == numberofatt :
            return 'Game Finished'
    if user_ans != imag_ans[i]:
        global n
        n = n + 1
        #blank = 0
        print 'Try Again'
        return quiz(a)


print level()
```

Comment: There's no such thing as an "if loop"

Comment: It's not even clear what you're asking.

Comment: Also you might want to check how `global` works.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `while` loop:

```
def level():
    global a
    a = raw_input('Please select Level? (Easy / Medium / Hard): ')
    pending = True
    while pending:
        if a == 'Easy':
            pending = False
            return attempts()
        elif a == 'Medium':
            pending = False
            return 'Med'
        elif a == 'Hard':
            pending = False
            return 'Hard'
        else :
            print 'Invalid option'
            print '\n'
```

Something similar could be applied for `quiz()`. As commented, you should check how global works. Also, revise the indentation (e.g.: in `att()`).